# Selenium: adding cookies won't login into website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, session, cookies, undetected-chromedriver

I'm working with selenium and undetected chromedriver. I have a simple script that goes to a link, wait for me to sign in and then it gets all the cookies from the website.
I do so with the goal of avoiding logging in each time i use the bot.

This is the script that store the cookies:

```
from undetected_chromedriver import Chrome
import json

d = Chrome()
d.maximize_window()
d.get('https://www.yourwebsite.com')

input('store cookies:')

with open('cookies/yourwebsite.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(d.get_cookies(), indent=2))

d.close()
d.quit()
```

and this instead is the part that load them from the .json file:

```
from undetected_chromedriver import Chrome
import time
import json

d = Chrome()
d.maximize_window()
d.get('https://www.yourwebsite.com')

with open('cookies/yourwebsite.json', 'r') as f:
    cookies = json.loads(f.read())

for cookie in cookies:
    try:
        if 'expiry' in cookie and type(cookie['expiry']) == type(0):
            print(cookie['expiry'], round(time.time()))
            cookie['expiry'] = round(time.time()) + 6000
        d.add_cookie(cookie)
    except Exception as e: print(e)
d.refresh()


input(':')
d.close()
d.quit()
```

This seem to work with some website and don't with others. What am i missing?

Here is an example of cookies from a website which i can login using this method:

```
[
  {
    "domain": "www.sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1729693505,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "kampyleSessionPageCounter",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "None",
    "secure": true,
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "domain": "www.sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1729693505,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "kampyle_userid",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "None",
    "secure": true,
    "value": "0cf6-ea89-933b-8419-415f-535d-6419-337b"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1698158705,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "login_fr",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "codiceConto=2935807876855730%3Btoken=E6A9967451C3EF22CCB2BDCC379E51E3%3Bpvd=GE9005%3BbillCodeId=5130846%3Bic=5130846%3Bmm=ffc91e510f951b9b9826c91e2aa8cef7%3Bprodotti=[1%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C11%2C12%2C13%2C14%2C15]%3BultimoDepAmount=5000%3Bap_id_cliente=964296B553E5E2ADBDF531A266AA7A32%3BultimoDepTstamp=06/09/2023+20:28:18%3BprimoDepTstamp=06/09/2023+20:28:18%3Bap_campagna=3262%3Bat_id_affiliato=3503%3Bat_id_partner=465%3Bat_id_campagna=3262%3Bmn_id_affiliato=3503%3Bap_servizio=465%3BprimoDepAmount=5000%3Bap_affiliato=3503%3Bmn_id_campagna=3262%3Bmn_id_partner=465%3BidSessione=node0hoj8ih5bdeueju9xqk13b77s609926-org.apache.sling"
  },
  {
    "domain": "www.sisal.it",
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "userInfo",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "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"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1698159304,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "s_gpv_pn",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "homepage"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1732717504,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "s_lv",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "1698157504571"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1705933504,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "s_nr",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "1698157504571-New"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "primoDepTstamp",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "06/09/2023-20:28:18"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1732717504,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_ga",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "GA1.1.561969277.1698157470"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1698164669,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "bm_sv",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": true,
    "value": "C93F52B70D6D8A1067185461D6584F71~YAAQSX4ZuPU/Q02LAQAAxSsTYhUWH0UAI0KA658PTWfLIvw1n/pJSzdhg7LIuoHmuSfTvAB5Beyc0iSh4BTNGlVN+3PVjMM6NGOSp7gqBuPmUaIejr10EmEMs7ZUB5i286r0oNmjLYfd92yy8DD7CZWk3ot0r8vtLl/YXncmABZmp4YdHXklYtczWuSMc8LZlx6kuIX7jw0fYsQnH4XXWXZ+EDmq5/dhLFmWXQZ/NhR/ful1HHokSvfg+kWF1LE=~1"
  },
  {
    "domain": "www.sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1698159307,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "name": "akaalb_www",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "None",
    "secure": true,
    "value": "1698159307~op=www_aem:farm-c-www-aem|~rv=13~m=farm-c-www-aem:0|~os=19998e1be61d868e4c1c9f44b9332069~id=05a7da72345a38cf04db435f62fd6279"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1732717504,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_ga_2F7HDG66KD",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "GS1.1.1698157469.1.1.1698157504.0.0.0"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1698243904,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "mm_dp_ct",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "ffc91e510f951b9b9826c91e2aa8cef7"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "lg_idc",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "5130846"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1732717504,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "s_ecid",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "MCMID%7C92225235972847875704534639001189866603"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "rxVisitor",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "16981574687556J8D0SQ7UIKFBS1L07E06S5EVV0CHJBR"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1729693504,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "utag_main",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "v_id:018b62129ecf00af1c8f50a4d25005065001505d00bd0$_sn:1$_se:7$_ss:0$_st:1698159304312$ses_id:1698157469394%3Bexp-session$_pn:3%3Bexp-session$_prevpage:undefined%3Bexp-1698161104332$vapi_domain:sisal.it"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "gameBreakSet",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": true,
    "value": "login"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1698158705,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "login",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "codiceConto=2935807876855730%3Btoken=E6A9967451C3EF22CCB2BDCC379E51E3%3Bpvd=GE9005%3BbillCodeId=5130846%3Bic=5130846%3Bmm=ffc91e510f951b9b9826c91e2aa8cef7%3Bprodotti=[1%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C11%2C12%2C13%2C14%2C15]%3BultimoDepAmount=5000%3Bap_id_cliente=964296B553E5E2ADBDF531A266AA7A32%3BultimoDepTstamp=06/09/2023+20:28:18%3BprimoDepTstamp=06/09/2023+20:28:18%3Bap_campagna=3262%3Bat_id_affiliato=3503%3Bat_id_partner=465%3Bat_id_campagna=3262%3Bmn_id_affiliato=3503%3Bap_servizio=465%3BprimoDepAmount=5000%3Bap_affiliato=3503%3Bmn_id_campagna=3262%3Bmn_id_partner=465%3BidSessione=node0hoj8ih5bdeueju9xqk13b77s609926-org.apache.sling"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "AMCVS_45974CD958010CB40A495E7C%40AdobeOrg",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "domain": "www.sisal.it",
    "httpOnly": true,
    "name": "JSESSIONID",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": true,
    "value": "node0hoj8ih5bdeueju9xqk13b77s609926.node0"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1698159304,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "s_dur",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "1698157470022"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1732717504,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "AMCV_45974CD958010CB40A495E7C%40AdobeOrg",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "1585540135%7CMCMID%7C92225235972847875704534639001189866603%7CMCIDTS%7C19655%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCOPTOUT-1698164704s%7CNONE%7CMCAAMLH-1698762304%7C6%7CMCAAMB-1698762304%7Cj8Odv6LonN4r3an7LhD3WZrU1bUpAkFkkiY1ncBR96t2PTI%7CMCSYNCSOP%7C411-19662%7CvVersion%7C4.4.0"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1729693498,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_abck",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": true,
    "value": "A94E8CF3E91705BE957767576C958A8D~0~YAAQ0BXfrWwXE2GLAQAAPBITYgoRo//9OTekXwIJcIA9TimGyUXXtZYxDjvMkefENihRWv117aKupijy3n9JrtcTiFiIchJTt33KdcLsjP1AYKw28Ujk39ZSrsOtgXs/VUZEivg4QXftnBGe9nelLvd3MkzDWTCLZYHzbRmzKYVdcKq6cEheLEtT/dJ5akTwvN2xYq45NKCSZlgtQM4uJ7+Eg6Jyk+54EuVvJYQ2kmIO866jOy0bb3ycrqRMsUx7MKl8j8ri2kNSMLKfKYmqgF8K8S2GlYzV4shv/U9FnKKyIBb+UOLUSWZPubXPhMdQxhNt8FXXC1ERCWntRiRC0gjcNDhGRX0sLm55FZJ9v89ZqUfq9OFQuOA0CXmiBTJqDAWSAIkbofchObio5pncTGBlaELf~-1~-1~-1"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "s_sq",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "sisalpreprod%3D%2526pid%253Dlogin%25253Alogin%2526pidt%253D1%2526oid%253DfunctionSn%252528%252529%25257B%25257D%2526oidt%253D2%2526ot%253DBUTTON"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1729693501,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "OptanonAlertBoxClosed",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "2023-10-24T14:25:01.026Z"
  },
  {
    "domain": "www.sisal.it",
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "channelId",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "62"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "rxvt",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "1698159271269|1698157468756"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1698159304,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "s_ivc",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "true"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1698158705,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "JWT",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": true,
    "value": "eyJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwidGFnIjoiaWhzbGplTTNYcGpJTFlXZXVuZFM3ZyIsImFsZyI6IkEyNTZHQ01LVyIsIml2IjoiVVJWNmg4VWVkUVB4VlJKOSJ9.KGdabBBNtHvXdyUIvO2wexi1JmfXEohmGZ-DO5mRNu4.O7PMDN4Alad_31sg.L_b_0VknyaCVrHThCqD5a6xrgIEiwamWgDcPMZyK2DWTsBewzTfkBYNKSF3uT1A4tYOeBOQhVr0jPeRQn9UMbshh8qsKv1pKu4FI62HOdUuTN6Nn7ExZeQWHiSp1zYlvaDKxRzqNOeTAkirRBZ8vujc-kie3_AgpsETkw1yhyydHHlgnkxu4nQ4n_yUM2acpKCffhQFFbXpm8kMsX2s7KUoKFjOqoCE_8RHoDZ23qszUEdDmz9fdp5uOjzJmyQQcUITAme1PeQMRw7hn-a9EoT5g0aZq1JSM2SUQabHfUAEZ_AL1aAtzHSCB563o431I9dVH2k8s5s8axKrLVdqmU1akf5aCbVHPI7M3I03oFyyxsE63HkqqbZ94YwJ22s-mk16hoGAdfIXQ4hzXE9vG_MsGRgMb9qk9sCzOoW1yoL1MW2SPAZe8H5xZ8uNXhxZVKaoMs9ectZkWtjQQM0cs9WjIJiPFYGSy60HuIDMGT5A8iLUywgEMRR0YWryD44HXRg8t5YOBuKdd45vDsehqNIGOluJlbqsXHS0PLQ.DR56j4u7hQHlxOAJS1i_gw"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1732717504,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "s_channelStack",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "%5B%5B%27Direct%2520Load%27%2C%271698157504573%27%5D%5D"
  },
  {
    "domain": "www.sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1729693505,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "mdigital_alternative_uuid",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "None",
    "secure": true,
    "value": "f513-e6f4-fef0-bfd1-f9f1-5a33-e6ad-d04b"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1698159305,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "kndctr_45974CD958010CB40A495E7C_AdobeOrg_cluster",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "None",
    "secure": true,
    "value": "irl1"
  },
  {
    "domain": "www.sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1729693505,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "kampyleUserSession",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "None",
    "secure": true,
    "value": "1698157505710"
  },
  {
    "domain": "www.sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1729693505,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "mdLogger",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "None",
    "secure": true,
    "value": "false"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1732717503,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "s_fid",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "6385568977472662-0ECC9D74DBE7FEAE"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1729720799,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "s_vnc365",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "1729693470023%26vn%3D1"
  },
  {
    "domain": "www.sisal.it",
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "pvd",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": true,
    "value": "GE9005"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1698243904,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_gid",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "GA1.2.281093548.1698157470"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1698164668,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "name": "ak_bmsc",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "9994BDFF245DEEC3994400FE8322CD4D~000000000000000000000000000000~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"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1732285470,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "kndctr_45974CD958010CB40A495E7C_AdobeOrg_identity",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "None",
    "secure": true,
    "value": "CiY5MjIyNTIzNTk3Mjg0Nzg3NTcwNDUzNDYzOTAwMTE4OTg2NjYwM1ITCKDCypC2MRABGAEqBElSTDEwAPABocLKkLYx"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "ultimoDepTstamp",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "06/09/2023-20:28:18"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "gvsC",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "New"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "dtCookie",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "v_4_srv_5_sn_JIPVNFBFVJJULCFO10IDG1AOO86R7NG6_perc_100000_ol_0_mul_1_app-3Af5087d32441d6d78_0_app-3A24666996558c94c6_0"
  },
  {
    "domain": "www.sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1729693505,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "kampyleUserSessionsCount",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "None",
    "secure": true,
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "SC_LINKS_S",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "%5B%5BB%5D%5D"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1698159304,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "akaalb_areaprivata_k8s",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "None",
    "secure": true,
    "value": "1698159304~op=areaprivata_k8s:farm-b-k8s-areaprivata|~rv=60~m=farm-b-k8s-areaprivata:0|~os=dd03fa8a11190c6108e78fa392bf53c1~id=cd91ef68385d664f1e0fa0ce80b900c1"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "dtPC",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "-15$157468752_386h1vPAPDDMCSSLDFFBOCAWMUIUEMHUMBVKNR-0e0"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "dtSa",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "-"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1698159304,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "s_lv_s",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "First%20Visit"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1729693504,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "OptanonConsent",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "isGpcEnabled=0&datestamp=Tue+Oct+24+2023+16%3A25%3A04+GMT%2B0200+(Central+European+Summer+Time)&version=6.23.0&isIABGlobal=false&consentId=c1cf561d-3ee9-4958-81cd-b589233ff52d&interactionCount=2&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0002%3A1%2CC0004%3A1%2CC0003%3A1&hosts=H13%3A1%2CH19%3A1%2CH21%3A1%2CH22%3A1%2CH23%3A1%2CH24%3A1%2CH26%3A1%2CH59%3A1%2CH28%3A1%2CH6%3A1%2CH8%3A1%2CH2%3A1%2CH33%3A1%2CH4%3A1%2CH64%3A1%2CH7%3A1%2CH27%3A1%2CH12%3A1%2CH222%3A1&AwaitingReconsent=false&geolocation=%3B"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "provParameter",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": ""
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "expiry": 1698171868,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "bm_sz",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "A26BACE220344ABAF042F9A1FAFCC8FF~YAAQSX4ZuNQoQ02LAQAAPZwSYhXOw7IOxCXzu2hIY4tmmNSefB2FLqwyCmoqn5h30dU7C0XN0cVpt0V+OxuHvAdJvIQCJWz3fbip/wAWqqFj8d54l3NG9vQStWoZ/nlJiIUNWKkV+VoWMLre7oZIBD6vL4VBnxH+J14UcA+/0k7f3dk3fMUD3vePAmwxANrtzI/NVnqvvJ+Ln5SgdO7omRMuJ9eyOiuTQViHFcoj56ACf+vdRQQ4aJOmM0jd7oWIgCdo42gEsRPx8cOa5G7ceCnsoa7o3lQgxPfxm2pyBfTA~3162680~3355973"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".sisal.it",
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "cm",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "Direct%20Load"
  }
]
```

Here insted an example from a website which i can't login with cookies:

```
[
  {
    "domain": ".lottomatica.it",
    "expiry": 1698250199,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_clsk",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "1r6h0jz|1698163799474|3|0|q.clarity.ms/collect"
  },
  {
    "domain": "www.lottomatica.it",
    "expiry": 1713715799,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "OptanonConsent",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "isGpcEnabled=0&datestamp=Tue+Oct+24+2023+18%3A09%3A59+GMT%2B0200+(Central+European+Summer+Time)&version=202211.1.0&isIABGlobal=false&hosts=&consentId=d25f376d-cddb-41bc-a2ed-a00e61e5c544&interactionCount=1&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0004%3A1%2CC0002%3A1%2CC0003%3A1"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".lottomatica.it",
    "expiry": 1698165599,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_cs_s",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "4.0.0.1698165599159"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".lottomatica.it",
    "expiry": 1732723799,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_ga_PS578M0MMR",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "GS1.2.1698163755.1.1.1698163799.0.0.0"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".lottomatica.it",
    "expiry": 1732723799,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_ga",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "GA1.1.1890999741.1698163752"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".lottomatica.it",
    "expiry": 1729699755,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_clck",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "et6kj8|2|fg4|0|1392"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".lottomatica.it",
    "expiry": 1732723799,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_ga_GYTSDDPY45",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "GS1.1.1698163755.1.1.1698163799.0.0.0"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".lottomatica.it",
    "expiry": 1732327755,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_cs_c",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "0"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".lottomatica.it",
    "expiry": 1732723799,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_ga_LBHFX99JDV",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "GS1.1.1698163752.1.1.1698163799.0.0.0"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".lottomatica.it",
    "expiry": 1698163812,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_gat_UA-232781850-2",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".www.lottomatica.it",
    "expiry": 1698768598,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "RT",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "\"z=1&dm=www.lottomatica.it&si=8e3f56f5-5726-4a9c-a7fa-930b090ac599&ss=lo4iunpn&sl=2&tt=1w2&obo=1&rl=1\""
  },
  {
    "domain": ".lottomatica.it",
    "expiry": 1729699766,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "cVuS",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".lottomatica.it",
    "expiry": 1713715755,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "OptanonConsent",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "isGpcEnabled=0&datestamp=Tue+Oct+24+2023+18%3A09%3A15+GMT%2B0200+(Central+European+Summer+Time)&version=202211.1.0&isIABGlobal=false&hosts=&consentId=d25f376d-cddb-41bc-a2ed-a00e61e5c544&interactionCount=1&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0004%3A1%2CC0002%3A1%2CC0003%3A1"
  },
  {
    "domain": "www.lottomatica.it",
    "expiry": 1698250199,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "c_prof",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "true"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".lottomatica.it",
    "expiry": 1732327755,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_cs_id",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "63ec5403-3442-a589-828b-e4b9ee3403da.1698163755.1.1698163799.1698163755.1.1732327755415"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".lottomatica.it",
    "expiry": 1698165555,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_cs_mk_ga",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "None",
    "secure": true,
    "value": "0.45279782602412055_1698163755271"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".www.lottomatica.it",
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "TS01ad7730",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "01ffae651b2e7559e75b2c4e62485717cc8d29e9ff22c245dd8be03f25459c2ef7ef1441446627e16799011250479aa3220414a9822440b6b33cb3568d04711054a240931c79d22d0191e78f5e3666b8c6f7a2837105e41af9147f282ec397a1e468b388b5"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".lottomatica.it",
    "expiry": 1698163815,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_gat_UA-232781850-1",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".lottomatica.it",
    "expiry": 1713715755,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "OptanonAlertBoxClosed",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "2023-10-24T16:09:15.252Z"
  },
  {
    "domain": ".lottomatica.it",
    "expiry": 1698250199,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "_gid",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "GA1.2.1611491714.1698163752"
  },
  {
    "domain": "www.lottomatica.it",
    "expiry": 1729699799,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "name": "fp_token_7c6a6574-f011-4c9a-abdd-9894a102ccef",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "None",
    "secure": true,
    "value": "i4L0nRPQKSRyHDMbIwgrr/1645TVHl0kUWyTbsUZzlU="
  },
  {
    "domain": "www.lottomatica.it",
    "expiry": 1729699766,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "cVuS",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "domain": "www.lottomatica.it",
    "httpOnly": false,
    "name": "TS019e4721",
    "path": "/area-personale",
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "secure": false,
    "value": "01ffae651b21c9f92a36248601c855bf1b707d454122c245dd8be03f25459c2ef7ef1441446627e16799011250479aa3220414a98244a3ec82e8e8626680d83288734e21ad2ea2bee78b58c3c176a0bbd454aefce6"
  },
  {
    "domain": "www.lottomatica.it",
    "httpOnly": true,
    "name": "JSESSIONID",
    "path": "/area-personale",
    "sameSite": "None",
    "secure": true,
    "value": "875Sr7CrxJqxIV7UfX7AM2zj0-U92kip88Yv3s2a.tg1-btrconto00"
  }
]
```

I tried everything, searched all SO posts about cookies but nothing seems to work and the fact that only some websites don't make me login with cookies is not helping... Thank you for your time